# Set Image over second Image

Tags: java, blackberry

I am new in blackberry, i am developing one blackberry application in which i am make a login screen where one white strip image are placed at top and logo should appear on that strip. so simply i have take two horizontalFieldManager for it and for strip it will display good but logo are stay below at strip.

**Here is my Code ::**

```
((VerticalFieldManager) getMainManager()).setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0xEDEDED));

        HorizontalFieldManager hfm =  new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER );
        HorizontalFieldManager hfm2 =  new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_VCENTER );
        Bitmap Topstrip = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
        Bitmap MoneLogo = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
        boolean lowRes = Display.getWidth() <= 320;
        if (lowRes)
        {
            // The device has a low resolution screen size
            Topstrip = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("topstripbg.png");
        }
        else
        {
            Topstrip = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("topstripbg-mdpi.png");
            MoneLogo= Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo72X72.png");
            // The device has a high resolution screen size

        }
        BitmapField TopstripimgField = new BitmapField(Topstrip);
        BitmapField MoneLogoimgField = new BitmapField(MoneLogo);

        hfm.add(TopstripimgField);
        hfm2.add(MoneLogoimgField);
        add(hfm);
        add(hfm2);
```

I want like this ::

```
--------------------------------------
 ____
|LOGO|           ** Strip ** 
|____|
--------------------------------------
```

Please also suggest me good UI Tutorial for best practice

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: come to the http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-iphone-and-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
final Bitmap bg=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png");
    VerticalFieldManager top = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bg.getWidth(),
                    bg.getHeight(), bg, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }

    };


final Bitmap logo= Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo.png");
top .add(new BitmapField(logo));
add(top);
```